# Hover transition on display block not working

Tags: css

I wanted to place some effect on an element hover. But I can't seem to make it work. Below are the html structure and css in my current project

```
<!-- HTML ELEMENT STRUCTURE -->
<div class="do-share">
    <ul class="social-container">
       <li>one</li>
       <li>two</li>
       <li>three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
/* CSS file */
.do-share:hover > .social-container{
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    top: -85px;
}
.social-container {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 2s linear;
}
```

But the transition effect on this does not work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You don't have a class "social-container" in the HTML code you have posted, just in the CSS.

Comment: sorry its a typo it should be typo. Updated my question

Comment: Instead of using display:none and block, try using visibility: hidden and visible. As long as your display is set to none, there will not be an element to mouse over in order to start your hover effect. Also, are you really wanting to transition everything on hover (i.e. position and list-style as well as visibility)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```css
.do-share:hover > .social-container{
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    top: 5px;
}
.social-container {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 2s linear;

}
.do-share{
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="do-share">
    <ul class="social-container">
       <li>one</li>
       <li>two</li>
       <li>three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try with opacity:

```
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="do-share">
      <ul class="social-container">
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

and css code:

```
body {
  color: #fff;
}

.do-share:hover .social-container {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 5s linear;
}

.social-container {
  opacity: 1;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.do-share {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```